# understanding dynamodb rubyclient logs

Tags: ruby, logging, colors, amazon-dynamodb

I have seen similar logs in other places as well but have failed to find a description of the format.

```
I, [2013-05-31T15:42:45.943114 #9000]  INFO -- : ←[1m←[34m[AWS DynamoDB 200 2.42
5242 0 retries]←[0m←[1m list_tables()  ←[0m
```

1. What units does the m represent?
2. How to understand left square brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those characters you are asking about are not part of the log itself, they are just special characters sequences used to colorize the text on terminals capable of displying colors, i.e. any terminal emulator on modern UNIX-like systems (maybe also on Windows?). What you see as `←` is actually an escape character (`<ESC>`).

Specifically: `<ESC>[1m` is the sequence to make the text "bright" (usually rendered with bold font), `<ESC>[34m` makes the font foreground color blue and `<ESC>[0m` reset the color to default.

More information about color escape sequences [here](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm#colors).

On a UNIX-like system you can see the colorized output using the `less` command like this:

```
less -R logfile.log
```